# Why would GCC/Clang accept const qualified object as initializer for object with static storage duration?

Tags: c, static, constants

As far as I know, the ISO C standard is strict about initializers for object with static storage duration in C11 [6.7.9 Initialization](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p4)

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.

But both GCC/Clang accepted the following code:

```c
const int i = 3; // const here should not make i a constant expression
static int j = i;
```

Even with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors`, the compilers above are not giving me any complaint.

However, these compilers do realize that `i` was not a constant expression. For example, Clang gave me:

> error: size of static array must be an integer constant expression

for the following code:

```c
const size_t sz = 3;
static int a[sz];
```

Am I getting anything wrong here?

Comment: Compiler extensions

Comment: @Achel Because the standard does not make it one. If you try using `i` as the size of an `static` array, your code would be rejected.

Comment: @klutt I was thinking the same. But these compilers do complains if other scenario that requires constant expression involves `i`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58699604/6699433

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't miss anything, it is indeed a not a strictly conforming C program, and a non-conforming behavior on the compiler's part. This is very likely caused by the both GCC and Clang being compiler suites for C++ as well. In C++ `i` is a valid initializer for `j`.

It's worth noting however that while compilers are free to translate non-conforming C programs at their discretion, they must still issue a diagnostic about the non-conformance according to C11 5.1.1.3 p1:

> A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic
> message (identified in an implementation-defined manner) if a
> preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a
> violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is
> also explicitly specified as undefined or implementation-defined.
> Diagnostic messages need not be produced in other circumstances.

Even if we accept the behavior as an extension, the fact GCC and Clang don't issue a diagnostic is conformance bug on both their parts.

Comment: It's not a non-conforming compiler, as there is also a clause that the compiler may accept other forms of constant expression besides what is mandated