# static struct initialization thread safety

Tags: c++, c, static, thread-safety

Given the following example:

```
struct test
{
    const char* data;
    const int number;
};

struct test* foo()
{
    static struct test t = {
        "this is some data",
        69
    };
    return &t;
}
```

is the call to `foo` thread safe? In other words, is the structure initialized only once in a thread-safe manner? Does it make a difference if this is compiled in C or C++?

Comment: In C++ it's thread safe. I don't know about C.

Comment: Related: [Is local static variable initialization thread-safe in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8102125/12149471)

Comment: The C and C++ initialization rules are quite different, so you should ask about one language at a time.

Comment: @Lundin: On the other hand, having a question about the differences between both languages could be useful. However, this would require an answerer to know the rules of both languages.

Comment: In C++, the initialisation of `t` is thread safe since C++11.   Before C++11, it was not thread safe (since earlier standards didn't have any provision related to threading at all).   I *believe* the initialisation of `t` is also thread safe in C, mostly because static variables can only be initialised with literals (compile time constants) in C [from which I infer that the structure will be initialised before any thread ever accesses it].

Comment: C doesn't have static initialization order or "static initialization fiascos". Nor does it have constructors or RAII. So this simply can't be thread unsafe in C. As for C++, they've made these rules quite complex post C++11.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Maybe but now 3 answers were posted and all are "wrong" since they do not address both languages. Bad questions lead to bad answers.

Comment: It thread-safe in C++. Now someone just needs to post a combined C/C++ answer.

Comment: The C++ part has several duplicates, so an answer could refer to that and focus on the C part.

Comment: @Lundin regarding "can't be thread unsafe in C" - what about assigning a static with the result of e.g. `malloc` ?

Comment: @wohlstad That's a constraint violation, since function calls are not compile-time constants. Specifically C17 6.7.9 "All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals."

Comment: @wohlstad C has been like that since the dawn of time, although C23 will bring a `constexpr` keyword giving some more options (not to be confused with C++). Also some [non-conforming compilers like gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68252570/why-are-const-qualified-variables-accepted-as-initializers-on-gcc) accept a few more options.

Answer (score 4):

The distinction exists in C/C++ prior to C++ 11 and in C++ 11 or later (Earlier standards lacked any provisions for threading.).

As you can see here: [C++ Static local variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#:%7E:text=If%20multiple%20threads,atomic%20boolean%20comparison.:%7E:text=If%20multiple%20threads,atomic%20boolean%20comparison.), **since C++11** is it guaranteed by the standard that a static local variable will be initialized only once. There is a specific note regarding locks that can be applied to ensure single initializing in a multi threaded environment:

> *If multiple threads attempt to initialize the same static local
> variable concurrently, the initialization occurs exactly once* (similar
> behavior can be obtained for arbitrary functions with std::call_once).
> Note: usual implementations of this feature use variants of the
> double-checked locking pattern, which reduces runtime overhead for
> already-initialized local statics to a single non-atomic boolean
> comparison.

The rules in C are specified here: [C Storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration#:%7E:text=static%20storage%20duration.%20The,have%20this%20storage%20duration.):

> static storage duration. The storage duration is the entire execution
> of the program, and *the value stored in the object is initialized only
> once, prior to main function*. All objects declared static and all
> objects with either internal or external linkage that aren't declared
> _Thread_local (since C11) have this storage duration.

Comment: You have now quoted the relevant rules of both languages. However, you have not directly answered the question. Does this mean that the initialization is thread-safe in both languages? If that is the case, then you may want to explicitly state it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since C++11, object initialization will be made only by one thread, other threads will wait till it complete. See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576022/efficient-thread-safe-singleton-in-c) for reference.

Comment: This answer may be correct for C++, but the question is also asking about the difference between the languages C and C++.