# initialiser element is not constant

Tags: c, initialization, embedded, constants

I want to create vector-table to create start-up code for MCU
when I try to put function address in to the vector-table the compiler produces an error: `initialiser element is not constant`

```
void reset_handler(void);

uint32_t const vector_table[] = {
    STACK_START,
    (uint32_t)&reset_handler
};

void rest_handler(void)
{
}
```

I always use function pointer type to create array of function but this time I want to know why when I use `uint32_t` type array I cannot put the address of a function in it

Comment: It is caused by the conversion to the wrong integer type. The message emmited by GCC is wrong https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=108875 & https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22020

Comment: Mohammad Pourbahram, Note that a function pointer may be wider than 32-bit.  C does not specify an integer type always wide enough for a function pointer.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica the vector table structure is same as ARM Cortex-M. Pointers and function pointers are 32 bit there.

Comment: You would do better in n any event to use `uintptr_t`>

Answer (score 3):

From the C Standard (6.6 Constant expressions)

> 6 An integer constant expression117) shall have integer type and shall
> only have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants,
> character constants, sizeof expressions whose results are integer
> constants, and floating constants that are the immediate operands of
> casts. **Cast operators in an integer constant expression shall only
> convert arithmetic types to integer types, except as part of an
> operand to the sizeof operator**.

This expression `(uint32_t)&reset_handler` with the cast operator used to initialize an integer is incorrect because the operand of the cast operator does not have an arithmetic type. So it may not be used to initialize integer objects (elements of an integer array) with static storage duration.

So the compiler issues the error

```
initialiser element is not constant
```

You could move the array declaration for example from the file scope in main. In this case the array will have automatic storage duration. Nevertheless in any case this casting `(uint32_t)&reset_handler` of a function pointer to an integer of the type `uint32_t` is wrong.

Comment: [6.6p9](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6p9) is relevant here:  "An address constant is a null pointer, a pointer to an lvalue designating an object of static storage duration, **or a pointer to a function designator**. ..."  OP needs to use an actual pointer and not use a dubious cast to `uint32_t`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle But he is trying to initialize an array of integers.:)

Comment: It is not wrong on the ARM Cortex-M targets. It has to be const to be places in the FLASH memory.

Comment: @0___________ And why does the compiler issue the error in your opinion?

Comment: I use avr-gcc and gcc compiler both of them give me same error

Comment: @MohammadPourbahram You cant use arv-compiler to compile code for ARM Cortex targets

Comment: @VladfromMoscow because converting function pointer to wrong integer type invokes UB. The error message is wrong. Probably bug

Comment: @0___________ Reread one more the error message. I doubt that it is a bug. It is a reasonable error message.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/3cj97YzTd and  https://godbolt.org/z/16YoK433r and https://godbolt.org/z/YoP9bx86a  You see? Sometimes it gives wring error messages. function pointers are constant expressions

Comment: @0___________ There are the same error message and a warning.  So it is not a bug of the compiler.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I am right https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22020 and my one which was marked as the dupe https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=108875

Comment: @0___________ According to the C Standard the error message is correct. There is no used a constant expression. See the quote from the C Standard I provided.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow it is not. Function reference is constant expression

Comment: @0___________ There is a casting of a function pointer. Pointers are not arithmetic types.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow `More latitude is permitted for constant expressions in initializers. Such a constant
expression shall be, or evaluate to, one of the following: ... an arithmetic type,` - read the rest in the standard. Conversion of function pointer evaluates to the integer type

Comment: @0___________ Function pointer to a static function is a constant expression of a function pointer type but casting it to integer is not a constant arithmetic type.

Comment: @0___________ In general this question is interesting. Maybe you should ask it to the C Standard Committee.

Answer (score -1):

> I use avr-gcc and gcc compiler both of them give me same error

The code shows that the vector table is for ARM-Cortex target. You cant use avr-gcc or x86 gcc to compiler code targeting ARM Cortex-M

You can't do this for the targer where sizeof function pointer is different that sizeof(uint32_t)

Using arm-gcc you can do this as the function pointer size is 4 bytes long and fits `uit32_t`.

It is a very common way of creating vector tables in C language on 32-bit Cortex-M targets.

https://godbolt.org/z/P3v77ah7K

```
#define STACK_START 0x2000000

void reset_handler(void);
const uint32_t vector_table[]  =
{
    STACK_START,
    (uint32_t)&reset_handler
};
void rest_handler(void)
{
}
```

and resulting code:

```
rest_handler:
        bx      lr
vector_table:
        .word   33554432
        .word   reset_handler
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252055/discussion-on-answer-by-0-initialiser-element-is-not-constant); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.